# Web application using websockets “Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, tomcat, websocket, connection

Java server, javascript client, no special libraries, plain text HTTP/1.1 and websocket connections.
Server side written (in Eclipse) using JDK 16 and a websocket jar found in Tomcat, version 10.0.2.  (Many permutations of other JDKs and websocket jars have also been tried.)
Two web applications.  Tomcat 10.0.2 on PC, 10.0.7 on server.  Both apps run on Windows 10.  Deployed to a Ubuntu 20.04 server.  Both programs display the initial HTTP data.  One program gets a websocket connection and works, the other fails to get the websocket connection.  Both use the same code to calculate the target URL for the websocket connection:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var target = "ws://" + location.host + "/[context]/[endpoint]";
    console.log("target: " + target);
    try {
        if ('WebSocket' in window) {
            socket = new WebSocket(target);
        } else if ('MozWebSocket' in window) {
            socket = new MozWebSocket(target);
        } else {
            alert('WebSocket is not supported by this browser.');
            return;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("websocket connection exception: " + e.description);
    }
...
```

Where only [context] and [endpoint] differ.  Recall that these URLs work on a PC.  I believe they are “well-formed”/valid.

Results for the web app that fails:

> Firefox:
>
> > uncaught exception: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
> > GET ws://35.xxx.xx.xx:8080/Memory/MemoryEndpoint[HTTP/1.1 404 70ms]
> > Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at  ws://35.xxx.xx.xx:8080/Memory/MemoryEndpoint.

> Chrome:
>
> > Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'encrypt' of undefined
> > at Object.13 (chrome-extension://bkdgflcldnnnapblkhphbgpggdiikppg/public/js/content-scripts/autofill.js:1427:33)
> > . . .
> > game.js:31 WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080/Memory/MemoryEndpoint' failed:

Chrome continues for many lines regarding the 'encrypt' undefined issue.  I have no idea what that is about but it might be very relevant.  The last line above implies that some reason for the failure might be given on the next line, but it is empty.

Neither browser logs the expected exception text beginning with: "websocket connection exception:".

Tomcat log files are all clean except for some curious entries in localhost__access_log such as:
`209.90.225.218 - - [11/Jul/2021:00:43:33 +0000] "HEAD /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 -` 
And others mentioning `/invoker/readonly, /login, /jenkins/login, /nifi/`.
The fact that both programs do return results from the Tomcat server tells me that permissions on ports etc are all sufficient.  I've also dug into netstat results and the like, reviewed firewall settings, read many many articles and requests for help.  (Probably irrelevant because Tomcat does return expected HTTP/1.1 data.)  No luck.

I need this program to work.  I would pay a cash reward for a solution to this by 07-16-2021, though I don't know how to discretely negotiate that.  :-(

Comment: I experienced the same chrome messages (but not any socket connection errors) and it was caused by a chrome extension. In my case it was "duck duck go" but any extension could be causing you issues. Try disabling any and all extensions and see if it helps?

Comment: Thanks lots for that suggestion.  I tried it.  Results are as you predicted: the mysterious Chrome 'encrypt' error message went away; but, alas, as you hinted, it did not affect the websocket error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, though I don't understand the cause.  Recall: the web application ran fine on development PC deployed to Tomcat version 10.0.2, for various JDKs, websocket libraries (including one found in the Tomcat 10.0.7 that had been installed on the VM).  The app failed on the Ubuntu VM.  A friend installed Tomcat 10.0.8 in the VM.  Presto!  websockets work.